# Who generates the default page of django welcome page?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I just set up the django environment and as the tutorial said. I typed `python manager.py runserver` and it told me to open `127.0.0.1:8000`. When I open it, it worked with the correct welcome page.

But here is my question: who generates this default welcome page? Since there is no `views.py` and the `urls.py` page is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `django/core/handlers/base.py` and `django/views/debug.py`.  In a nutshell, if django gets a 404, which it will if you don't have any routes set up, then in base.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.views import debug
    response = debug.technical_404_response(request, e)
```

And in debug.py look at `technical_404_response` and `empty_urlconf`

Answer (score 14):

If anyone would like to have it back (or reuse it), you just need to add `debug.default_urlconf` view to your `urls`:

```
…
from django.views import debug
…

urlpatterns = [
    …
    path('', debug.default_urlconf),
    …
]
```

Comment: was looking exactly for this. no thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If your `urls.py` is empty (as in contains no patterns to match urls) and Django is in debug mode (`DEBUG = True` in your settings) then Django fires back the page you're seeing.

**The Django view:**

https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/views/debug.py#L575-L583

**The HTML template:**

https://github.com/django/django/blob/ca9872905559026af82000e46cde6f7dedc897b6/django/views/templates/default_urlconf.html

Answer (score 5):

(**Disclaimer**: I am using django version: 3.2.5, In older versions the file content may vary)

The default landing page that you see when you run your django web app for first time is "**default_urlconf.html**". It's a fall safe mechanism added by django rather than giving 404 error in absence of any default url/routes.

When you first create a django website using commands like `django-admin startproject <project_name>` or using any IDE menu control like in case of "Pycharm professionals", you get the following folder structure. Also, the Debug is set as True (`DEBUG = True`) in your setting.py file

[image]

Additionally,
when the route is not set or the url maps are empty in url.py then the django framework provides default route through its error handling code.
It's like when you try to access/request http://127.0.0.1:8000/ django checks if that url exist or not(404) and also if the debug mode is active. This request is traversed through various *.py files like `base.py` ,`handlers.py`, `exceptions.py`, and finally it goes to `debug.py`. All these files are provided with virtual environment or the moment you (install django in your project).

Eventually, From "exception.py" it goes to "debug.py" through method `**debug.technical_404_response(request, exc)**`

```
def response_for_exception(request, exc):
    if isinstance(exc, Http404):
        if settings.DEBUG:
            response = debug.technical_404_response(request, exc)
        else:
            response = get_exception_response(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), 404, exc)
```

finally it sense that `debug.py` has `def technical_404_response(request, exception)` which calls `def default_urlconf(request)` and eventually it returns the response of a default html page (***default_urlconf.html***) that you see on the screen

```
def default_urlconf(request):
    """Create an empty URLconf 404 error response."""
    with Path(CURRENT_DIR, 'templates', 'default_urlconf.html').open(encoding='utf-8') as fh:
        t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
    c = Context({
        'version': get_docs_version(),
    })

    return HttpResponse(t.render(c), content_type='text/html')
```

[image]

**location of files:**

- ***exception.py***:
  venv/Lib/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py
- ***debug.py***: venv/Lib/site-packages/django/views/debug.py
- ***default_urlconf.html*** :
  venv/Lib/site-packages/django/views/templates/default_urlconf.html