# Django url cannot be found after editting urlpatterns

Tags: python, django

I'm playing with Django python tutorial and notice a very odd url behavior.
My project name is 'mysite', and in its urls.py, it by default has

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

This shows that little rocket base page when I visit localhost:8000.

Then I editted like following,

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('student/', include('student.urls'))
]
```

to indicate a new url for my own app, this time the base page localhost:8000 returns a 404. I'm very curious why my new line will affect the base page? BTW my django version is 3.0.6.

Comment: is there any error log from terminal or from website

Comment: @FA Yes.  Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

student/
admin/
The empty path didn't match any of these.

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14951468/2785080
and this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14951589/2785080 ::: Basically since in the first part you don't have any paths (besides admin) django sends you to the rocket, but once you add some urls, django now gives you 404 errors.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Ben. Does this also mean the base page is also under my own customization?

Comment: You aren't defining any base page above (`localhost:8000/`), so you won't see anything until you create/define it, just a 404.