# Error the requested resource was not found on this server after reverse proxying Nginx+Docker+Django project

Tags: django, docker, nginx, django-rest-framework, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am having a problem when I attempt to access **localhost/auth/** this is possibly because of the nginx configuration or may be another other issue. The following is the result I get from nginx logs after attempting to make a request to the proxied address  **localhost/auth/**

```
reverse-proxy      | 0.0.0.0 - - [28/Aug/2020:08:21:47 +0000] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 404 159 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
```

When I access **http://localhost/admin/** the Admin login page renders as expected as shown below. Also at **http://localhost/doc/** the [redocs documentation](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc) page renders as well.

[image]

## Project Structure

```
├── nccggbot
│     ├── chatbot/
│     └── core/
│     │     ├── __init__.py
│     │     ├── asgi.py
│     │     ├── settings.py
│     │     ├── urls.py
│     │     ├── wsgi.py
│     ├── static/
│     │     ├── admin/
│     │     ├── django_extensions/
│     │     |── drf-yasg
│     │     ├── rest_framework
│     │ 
│     ├── Dockerfile
│     ├── manage.py
│     ├── requirements.txt
│ 
│    
├──reverse_proxy/
│   ├── default.conf
│   └── Dockerfile
├──docker-compose-deploy.yml
├──README.md
```

**core/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,path

from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from drf_yasg import openapi
from rest_framework import permissions
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static 


schema_view = get_schema_view(
   openapi.Info(
      title="NCCG ChatBot API",
      default_version='v1.0.0',
      description="The nccg chatbot rest API",
   ),
   public=True,
   permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
)


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('doc/', schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-redoc'),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api/', include('chatbot.urls'))
]
```

## settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for core project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent


DEBUG = bool(int(os.environ.get("DEBUG", default=0)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY =  os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# ALLOWED_HOSTS_ENV = os.environ.get('ALLOWED_HOSTS')

# if ALLOWED_HOSTS_ENV:
#     ALLOWED_HOSTS.extend(ALLOWED_HOSTS_ENV.split(','))


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'chatterbot.ext.django_chatterbot',
    'rest_framework',
    'drf_yasg',
    'chatbot'
]

# ChatterBot settings

CHATTERBOT = {
    'name': 'NCCG Support Bot',
    'django_app_name': 'django_chatterbot'
}


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

print(DEBUG)

DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME':  'db.sqlite3',
        }
    }


# if DEBUG is False:
#     DATABASES = {
#         'default': {
#             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#             'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
#         }
#     }

# else:
#     DATABASES = {
#     "default": {
#         "ENGINE": os.environ.get("SQL_ENGINE", "django.db.backends.sqlite3"),
#         "NAME": os.environ.get("SQL_DATABASE", os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3")),
#         "USER": os.environ.get("SQL_USER", "user"),
#         "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("SQL_PASSWORD", "password"),
#         "HOST": os.environ.get("SQL_HOST", "localhost"),
#         "PORT": os.environ.get("SQL_PORT", "5432"),
#     }
#     }


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/vol/web/static'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/vol/web/media'

# STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
```

## NGINX conf file

```
upstream webserver {
    server nccgbot-service:8000;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    gzip on;

    location /auth {
        proxy_pass http://webserver/api-auth;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
    }

    location /doc {
        proxy_pass http://webserver/doc;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://webserver;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
    }


    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /vol/static;
    }

}
```

## Docker compose file

```
version: '3.7'

services: 
  # Chat bot 
  nccgbot-service:
    container_name: nccgbot-service
    image: nccgbot-service
    build:
      context: ./nccgbot_service

    command: sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py collectstatic --no-input  && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn core.wsgi:application --workers 2 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"

    volumes:
      - static_data:/vol/web

    env_file:
      - ./.env

    expose: 
      - "8000"

    restart: on-failure
  
  # proxies requests to internal services
  reverse_proxy:
    build:
      context: ./reverse_proxy
    restart: always
    image: reverse-proxy
    container_name: reverse-proxy
    volumes:
      - static_data:/vol/static

    ports:
      - "80:80"

    depends_on:
      - nccgbot-service

volumes:
  static_data:
```

**chatbot/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from chatbot.views import ChatterBotApiView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^chatbot/', ChatterBotApiView.as_view(), name='chatbot'),
]
```

**Browser output when I access `localhost/api-auth` **

[image]

Comment: based on **path('api/', include('chatbot.urls'))** I am assuming you have urls.py placed in chatbot directory but it's not showing up in project structure tree you added? Also, can you an confirm that you can access **localhost/api-auth/** and **localhost/api/** ?

Comment: @from_the_docs yes I have the urls placed  however I can't can access **localhost/api-auth** and **localhost/api/** I get the error **The requested resource was not found on this server.** I was expecting to access django rest frameworks **auth** urls from  **localhost/api-auth** but I get the same error. The django rest framework's browsable api is not rendering.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think this has something to with hyphen in `proxy_pass http://webserver/api-auth;` line in `location /auth` block in nginx config file. Can your can change **api-auth** path in urls.py to **api_auth** and then update corresponding line in nginx config file to `proxy_pass http://webserver/api_auth;`. I hope that would work.

Comment: @from_the_docs Am afraid that didn't work the weird thing is that I can easily access **localhost/admin** but  **localhost** doesn't which I should expect to see a page containing the list of the **urls** the Django default pages and Django rest framework pages are not been rendered for some reason yet all the assets are placed in **static** folder where NGINX expects them to be.

Comment: oh, i think your **localhost/auth/** is being resolved to **localhost/api** instead of **localhost/api-aith** by nginx based on **location /auth** rule in config file as shown in nginx log line you posted. that's why i though this might have something to do with hyphen. can you can try removing the entire **location /auth** block in nginx config file and try accessing **localhost/api-auth**?

Comment: Removed it the error still persists `The requested resource was not found on this server`

Comment: @PhilipMutua can you please post how you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

rest_framework.urls does not have an index view:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='rest_framework/login.html'), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```

So `/auth/login` should work. Also, it's not going to do what you think it does. This serves up Django's standard login and logout views and doesn't authenticate via REST. Look at [third party packages](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#third-party-packages) for that.
And look at [Django Vue Auth Demo](https://github.com/danjac/django-vue-auth-demo) for a discussion of some of the common mistakes and pitfalls when authenticating via REST using a detached frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Reason was Debug = False in Settings.py and the installation is fresh in production.
Solution  for me was to set Debug = True until after you define views.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951468/who-generates-the-default-page-of-django-welcome-page#:~:text=If%20your%20urls.py%20is,the%20page%20you're%20seeing.&text=The%20default%20landing%20page%20that,html%22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951468/who-generates-the-default-page-of-django-welcome-page#:%7E:text=If%20your%20urls.py%20is,the%20page%20you%27re%20seeing.&text=The%20default%20landing%20page%20that,html%22).

If your urls.py is empty (as in contains no patterns to match urls) and Django is in debug mode ( DEBUG = True in your settings) then Django fires back the page you're seeing. The default landing page that you see when you run your django web app for first time is "default_urlconf. html".